# Azure-blob NBlog config/settings.json could not be found

Tags: json, azure, azure-storage

On github there is an open-source project called NBlog. Its description is “A lightweight blog engine built with ASP.NET MVC5, Razor, jQuery and C#”. Once downloaded, opened in Visual Studio Community edition 2013, and I hit F5 (RUN) I get a yellow page of death saying the following

[image: yellow page of death]

I have posted an issue on github but have gotten no response.

[Issue # 28](https://github.com/ChrisFulstow/NBlog/issues/28)

As you can tell, I have established an Azure account, along with storage. I created a blob container called blustor1.
I found this blog post detailing

[Uploading An Object As JSON To Windows Azure Blob Storage](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2012/06/24/uploading-an-object-as-json-to-windows-azure-blob-storage/)

something almost identical, except the following line of code

```
GetBlockBlobReference(blobAddressUri);
```

vs.

`GetBlockBlobReference(relativePath);` AzureBlobRepository.cs line 54

Alex uses an absolute URI where as NBlog uses a relative path
Can someone help this newbie to Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-reference: [github issues link](https://github.com/ChrisFulstow/NBlog/issues/28)

I just added the connection string value but it still did not fix the original error message

```
<add name="AzureBlobEndpointURL" connectionString="https://xxx1.blob.core.windows.net/json" />
```

The following file is present on my disk;

NBlog.Web/App_Data/localhost/Config/settings.json

Here is the content of the settings.json file on my disk

```
{
"Site": "localhost-8080",
"Theme": "Default",
"MetaDescription": "NBlog, an ASP.NET MVC 3.0 blog platform.",
"Heading": "NBlog",
"Title": "NBlog",
"Tagline": "A blog platform for ASP.NET MVC developers",
"Crossbar": "ASP.NET MVC 3.0, Razor, JSON.NET, Markdown, Autofac, AntiXSS, HTML5 & CSS3, OpenID, NSubstitute, ELMAH",
"Admins":
[
    "http://cxfx.myopenid.com/"
],
"GoogleAnalyticsId": "",
"TwitterUsername": "twitter",
"ContactForm":
{
    "RecipientName": "NBlog Admin",
    "RecipientEmail": "nblog-admin@mailinator.com",
    "Subject": "NBlog contact form"
},
Cloud:
{
    "ConsumerKey": "DropBox_Key",
    "ConsumerSecret": "DropBox_Secret",
    "UserToken": "DropBox_UserToken",
    "UserSecret": "DropBox_UserSecret"
},
Disqus:
{
    "Shortname": "",
    "DevelopmentMode": true
}
}
```

Comment: Delete your answer to remove it.